# Can we tell whether two random variables are independent just by looking at their joint PDF?

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, uniform-distribution

**Question**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent uniform random variables on $[1, 2]$. Define $U = \min\{ X, Y \}$ and $V = max \{X, Y \}$.

Show that the joint PDF of $U$ and $V$ is given by
$$ f_{U,V}(u,v) = cI(-1 \leq u \leq v \leq 2),$$
where $I(\cdot)$ is an indicator function and $c$ is a constant to be determined.

Can we determine whether or not $U$ and $V$ are independent just by looking at the joint PDF? If yes, what do you conclude about their independence and why?

**My thoughts**

I think I can show the joint PDF as requested but I have some doubts about my answer to the second part of the question. In particular, I think we are able to conclude that $U$ and $V$ are not independent just by looking at the joint PDF because the upper bound of $u$ is determined by $v$ as seen in the range of the indicator function (and conversely the lower bound of $v$ is determined by $u$).

Would my conclusion and reasoning be correct? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One has the following result: Random variables $U,V$ are independent if and only if $f_{U,V}(u,v) = g(u)h(v)$ for some functions $g,h$. In particular, $g,h$ need not be the densities of $U$ and $V$. So it is generally very hard to conclude whether two random variables are dependent or not just by looking at the joint density. Namely your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for your comment! I understand that, but I am also thinking that the fact that the lower bound of $v$ is determined by $u$ kind of means that $u$ and $v$ are not independent too? For example, not knowing $u$, I might know nothing about $v$. However, after, say, knowing that $u < 1$, I now that $v > 1$, which gives me more information on $v$ that I had at first. Doesn’t this make sense?